# FFmpeg frame counter + resolution/bitrate/FPS box

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

I was trying to use `drawtext` FFmpeg filter to insert a frame counter at the bottom of my video by using this command:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/fonts/consola.ttf: text='Frame\\: %{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2\*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=50: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy output.mp4`

So far all works fine. I was wondering how could I insert also a resolution/bitrate box at the top of the video as shown in the image below:

[image: A frame in question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no builtin option for drawing resolution bitrate and frame rate, so we have to define an environment variable, and pass it to FFmpeg.

Formatting a string in Windows shell, is messy and the following "single line" example is far from perfect:

`for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('ffprobe "-v" "error" "-select_streams" "v:0" "-show_entries" "stream=width,height" "-of" "csv=s=x:p=0" "input.mp4"') do set "resolution=%i" && for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('ffprobe "-v" "error" "-select_streams" "v:0" "-show_entries" "stream=bit_rate" "-of" "csv=p=0" "input.mp4"') do set "bitrate=%i" && for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('ffprobe "-v" "error" "-select_streams" "v:0" "-show_entries" "stream=r_frame_rate" "-of" "csv=p=0" "input.mp4"') do set "framerate=%i" && set str='%resolution% / %bitrate% bps / %framerate% fps' && ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/fonts/consola.ttf:text='%str%':x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2\*lh):fontcolor=black:fontsize=50:box=1: boxcolor=white:boxborderw=5" -c:a copy output.mp4`

---

- Use FFprobe, for getting the resolution, bitrate and frame rate (I didn't try to convert the bitrate from bps to kbps).
  Adding `-pretty` argument format the rate to `1.672451 Mbit/s`.
- Assign the output of FFmpeg to variables as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable-using-a-ms-batch-file) (all the solutions are not very elegant).
- `set str='%resolution% / %bitrate% bps / %framerate% fps'` - formats the final string to the environment variable `str`.
- `text='%str%'` draws the content of variable `str`.
- `&&` is used for concatenating the 4 commands into single line.
  Note: [FFprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) is executed 3 times, because it looks like there is no option to add custom text between elements (we better look for more elegant solution).

Removing the `/` from the `60/1` is possible using shell string manipulation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503925/remove-last-characters-string-batch): `set frate=%framerate:~0,-2%`.

Use `drawtext` filter twice (separated by comma) for drawing two text boxes.

--

Output example:
[image]

---

Note:
The solution would be much more elegant using scripting language like Python, instead of Windows console.